# Capistrano fetch with block

Tags: ruby, capistrano

How block param means in Capistrano fetch function?

```
fetch(:release_path) { current_path }
```

Also it can be called with default?

```
fetch(:release_path, 'default') { current_path }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block and second argument are both used to provide default values.

For example:

```
# If :some_var is not set, then the default is used

fetch(:some_var) { "default" }
=> "default"

fetch(:some_var, "default")
=> "default"

# Once :some_var is set, the defaults are ignored

set(:some_var, "value")

fetch(:some_var) { "default" }
=> "value"

fetch(:some_var, "default")
=> "value"
```

You should never specify both a second argument and a block at the same time. In that case, the argument will be ignored and the block will be used.

```
# Don't do this, it is confusing
fetch(:another_var, "arg_default") { "block_default" }
=> "block_default"
```

The reason for choosing one form over another depends on the type of default value. If the default value is hard-coded (like a literal string in the above examples), then the argument form makes sense. On the other hand, if the default value is a computed value (i.e. a method call), then it is better to use a block.

The default-value behavior of Capistrano's `fetch` mimics that of Ruby's built-in `Hash#fetch`, which is documented here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch